# How NATURAL JOIN works with two tables when there are two or more common columns?

Tags: sql

How NATURAL JOIN works with two tables when there are two or more common columns? For example if i have tableA with columns A.A, A.B and A.C and tableB with columns B.A, B.B and B.D and I type: select * from A NATURAL JOIN B, which will be the column of the NATURAL JOIN, A or B (they are both common)?

Comment: What happened when you tried? (and besides: this is one of the reasons why `natural join` should not be used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ISO/IEC 9075-2:1999 (E) section 7.7 :

> If NATURAL is specified, then let common column name be a `<column name>` that is the
>   `<column name>` of exactly one column of T1 and the `<column name>` of exactly one column
>   of T2. [...]Let corresponding join columns refer to all columns of T1
>   and T2 that have common column names, if any.
>
> [...]
>
> If NATURAL is specified or `<named columns join>` is specified, then
>
> Case:
>
> i) If there are corresponding join columns, then let T be the multiset of rows of CP for
>   which the corresponding join columns have equal values.

So according to the standard if there are two common column-names the join will be based on all two columns.

Comment: Thanks for the help